# Illustrator 3D extrude on text misses faces

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, 3d, cs5

I am attempting to create 3D text in **Adobe Illustrator CS5** in OSX using the `3D Extrude` and `Bevel` effect.

The problem is that if I only rotate the text on one axis, in this case the `X axis` and then give it perspective, the resulting object is missing a few of the faces of the 3d object. This results in some incorrect white space.

Is there any way to correct or work around this bug to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: As for me, moving the interested points with the direct selection tool (just 1px in some directions) seems to be the only way to fix this issue...

Comment: The problem usually happens to every designer in Adobe Illustrator. I am using Adobe Illustrator CS 6 and faces same problems many times.<br />
I just try to solve it by adjusting perspective value. Try it yourself and let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Try adjusting the perspective by 1.

There are some instances were the perspective will cause faces to drop out. Usually a very minor adjustment in rotation or perspective will help those faces reappear.

Comment: Thanks, I found that out before but I would rather not use it because it makes it off balance.

Comment: There's no other solution. You need to adjust rotation, perspective, or bevel to get the missing faces to appear.

Answer (score 2):

Add more control points in your line art, specifically whatever section is not appearing correctly.  If you have a curve that is acting funny in perspective, add more anchor points in it and it should begin to render correctly in 3d view.

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me too.

I found out what will fix it is if you change another `axis` and turn it back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look for the path associated with the missing face.
2. Add an anchor anywhere on that path.
3. Use the `Direct Selection Tool` to select the created anchor to convert the anchor point to `Smooth` instead of the default `Corner` type.

Answer (score -2):

Easy Fix: Add a Arc Warp with Values of `0,0,0`

Comment: This has no effect for the sample I tested it with